# Can I use my own AdMob ad powered android app?

Tags: android, admob

My app is published in android market. It has AdMod ads. Can I install and use it for daily use without negative consequences? I know I may not use real ad unit when testing. But is it also so when my app is already published on the market and I am the developer?

Comment: Did you find the answer? I kinda have the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the app as a normal client would then I would say yes. 
But I am not a lawyer.